# The facebook debugger is giving 500 error

Tags: facebook, debugging

The facebook debugger is giving 500 error for your webpage. It is unable to get my og metatags values. However, og metatags are present in the web page:

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%3A%2F%2Fstaging.eco.ca%2Fcommunity%2Fblog%2F5-fascinating-green-jobs-youve-never-heard-of%2F68170%2F

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at your IIS configuration. Something in there is refusing connections from anything that isn't a web browser.

Your page returns a 500 error for the [W3C validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fstaging.eco.ca%2Fcommunity%2Fblog%2F5-fascinating-green-jobs-youve-never-heard-of%2F68170%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0#fatal-errors) also.

Comment: Nice idea to try W3C validator, I thought it was only a Facebook error. I still don't have a solution tough.

Answer (score 2):

For me it was because when Facebook, Google or other robots access the page, they don't send a language like a browser does, and in the code we were using the browser language to determine the content language.

Comment: That's it! FB robot has no `Accept-Language`! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I want to share my experience about this facebook debugger 500 error. I was getting this error without any explanation on facebook debugger. I checked my server side and domain records, tried what I found on internet with no luck. It took me long time to discover the problem.

Problem was I was sharing url within a restricted area in my website while sharing for first time. Let me explain, I have a test page in my cms, before I publish anything, I test if everything's ok. I realised whenever I test a content, facebook tries to crawl site, but it's in a restricted area. So I moved anything about facebook from my test page.